# How do I set java jvm properties from run time

Tags: java

I have tried the following code but java still says it cannot find the values. It only works if I set them in JVM before I even run my code. I just want to load them using a properties file.
In my case file is being loaded put java properties is not being populated.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/vars.options");
    prop.load(in);
    in.close();
    System.setProperties(prop);
```

Comment: You are just loading properties from file into a Hashtable (Properties). You have to let Java know to apply them as system properties.

Comment: how? tried `System.setProperties(prop);`, it's still not wokring

Comment: Are these the System properties that your code needs, or are these that Java/JVM itself depends? Note that not every property that Java/JVM depends upon can be set this way (a few things may happen before your code is executed).

Comment: well, even without using the rest of the code (commenting it out), I try to set the property by `System.setProperties(prop);` and I try to get one of the properties and it's `null`.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect that `vars.options` file has some funky characters or format.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't set the properties object to the system properties.

You are missing:

`System.setProperties(prop);`

**Note**

Make sure to use a `try` / `catch` / `finally` statement and to close your stream in the `finally` block.

Alternatively, you can use Java 7's "try-with-resources" idiom, as `InputStream` is `AutoCloseable`.

**Example (Java 7 style)**

```
try (InputStream in = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/vars.options")){
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(in);
    System.setProperties(prop);
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
    // TODO handle
}
System.out.println(System.getProperty("my.key"));
```

If in your `src` root folder, the `vars.options` file contains:

`my.key=foo`

...

This will print:

`foo`

Comment: file is being loaded properly, I can print the output just fine, but its not changing JVM properties.

Comment: tried `System.setProperties(prop);`, it's still not wokring. null when trying to get property.

Comment: @anotherq it should be, if the system property is indeed set and exists by the time you invoke `System.getProperty(your key)`. Make sure your property key exists.

Comment: it does exist. really not sure why it's null.

Comment: @anotherq See also example provided. If the value is `null` but no exception is thrown, make sure you have the right notation in your property file.

Comment: @anotherq on second thought, if your program is multi-threaded, make sure the property value doesn't get replaced by another running thread in between you populating the system props and retrieving the given property.